# First word from every line

Tags: java

Hi i have this code that prints last word of every line , i want something that do exactly that this code does but with first word (don't mock me i'm not a programmer)

```
private static void readFile1(String in, String out) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(in));

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    BufferedWriter writer = null;

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
          new FileOutputStream(out), "utf-8"));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.length() > 0)
        {
            String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
            //System.out.println(words[words.length - 1]);
            writer.write(words[words.length - 1]);
            writer.newLine();
        }          
    }

    br.close();
    writer.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
writer.write(words[words.length - 1]);
```

Use

```
writer.write(words[0]);//assuming you wont have empty line.
```

if you could have empty line, then try using:

```
if (words.length != 0) {
    writer.write(words[0]);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Dont forget to close this question by accepting the answer if this has helped so others can benefit from it in future.

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
writer.write(words[words.length - 1]);
```

with :

```
writer.write(words[0]);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Replace:
`writer.write(words[words.length - 1]);`
With: `writer.write(words[0]);`
Or use: 
`while((line = br.hasNextLine()))
    {...
        writer.write(words[0]);
    ...}`